# Android app to force the screen to turn off regardless of foreground app

Tags: android, display

Some Android apps keep the screen on while they are running.  That's usually okay, but sometimes it's not.

Is there an Android (KitKat compatible) app that will force the screen off even when the current app is trying to keep it on?

I would slightly prefer a non-root solution, but root apps are certainly welcome.

For this QA, I am interested in keeping the app running (in other words, preventing the device from sleeping), but just turning off the display.

For a related QA for allowing the device to sleep, see [this QA](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23176/android-app-to-force-sleep-mode-regardless-of-foreground-app).

Comment: @Izzy Does it matter if the OP doesn't want the solution involving a rooted device? Even if the OP doesn't want such a solution, your solution, if good enough, would serve well to those (having rooted device) coming to this site in future.

Comment: Btw: the same "Tasker-hint" applies here as well, additional plugin to mention might be *Secure Settings* here. Graphs for available tasks for both, *Tasker* and *Secure Settings*, can be found in my [Tasker resource collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) to investigate *before* installing them (to see if they promise the right thing).

Comment: @Firelord Sure, but the same could be said about many things. Primarily, answers should target the OP's requirements. Apart from that: As pointed out in my comment to the linked question, I don't have a "ready-to-use" solution (so I cannot answer). Others might be afraid to suggest root-based solutions ("might not fit") – so it's always better to point that out explicitly. Rocky did that in a perfect way, so both (root & non-root) parties are covered :)