# Android app to force sleep mode regardless of foreground app

Tags: android

Is there an Android (KitKat compatible) app that will force sleep mode after a specified amount of time, even when the current app is trying to keep the device on?

Ideally, the "specified amount of time" would be a manual trigger with a configurable amount of time; in other words, "X minutes from now".

I would slightly prefer a non-root solution, but root apps are certainly welcome.

For a related QA for not allowing the device to sleep, but keeping the screen on, see [this QA](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23175/android-app-to-force-the-screen-to-turn-off-regardless-of-foreground-app).

Comment: No specific experience with this special case, but first things coming to mind: Greenify plus Tasker, maybe plus another Tasker plugin. If you want to check this approach while waiting for answers, my [Tasker resource collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) could be a good starting point. Hint: Tasker provides shortcuts you can associate with its tasks; so if you were able to create a task doing what you need, you could place a shortcut to that on your homescreen.

Comment: I guess you can use [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en)  or [Servicely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.franco.servicely&hl=en) to play with your need